# Disable specific Unity lenses in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: unity, 15.04, unity-dash

I'm desperately trying to get rid of all those search results in the Unity dash. I've [followed](https://askubuntu.com/a/208177/5786) several [pages](https://askubuntu.com/a/455641/5786) but some things stubbornly remain even though their lens/scope doesn't seem to be present?!

--> How do I get rid of this?!

Here's what I still have:

```
torben@torben-desktop:~⟫ dpkg -l | grep scope
ii  libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop                     7.1.4+14.10.20140808-0ubuntu1                  all          binding to get places into the launcher - desktop def file
ii  libunity-scopes3:amd64                               0.6.16+15.04.20150410.3-0ubuntu1               amd64        API for Unity scopes integration
ii  unity-plugin-scopes:amd64                            0.5.4+15.04.20150410.2-0ubuntu1                amd64        QML plugin for Scopes
ii  unity-scope-calculator                               0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1                    all          Calculator scope for Unity
ii  unity-scope-home                                     6.8.2+15.04.20150311.1-0ubuntu1                amd64        Home scope that aggregates results from multiple scopes
ii  unity-scope-scopes                                   0.1+14.10.20140820-0ubuntu1                    amd64        A scope for browsing Unity scopes
ii  unity-scopes-master-default                          6.8.2+15.04.20150311.1-0ubuntu1                all          Home scope that aggregates results from multiple scopes
ii  unity-scopes-runner                                  7.1.4+14.10.20140808-0ubuntu1                  all          desktop runner for misceallenous scopes
torben@torben-desktop:~⟫ dpkg -l | grep lens
ii  liblensfun-data                                      0.2.8-2                                        all          Lens Correction library - Data
ii  liblensfun0                                          0.2.8-2                                        amd64        Lens Correction library - Runtime files
ii  unity-lens-applications                              7.1.0+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu2                  amd64        Application lens for unity
ii  unity-lens-files                                     7.1.0+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu1                  amd64        File lens for unity
torben@torben-desktop:~⟫
```

But in the actual dash, I still have a lot of crud:

[image]

I had also made sure that `system settings > Security & Privacy > Search > Include online search results` is off. Next time I checked, it was on again. I turned it off again. Now after yet another reboot it seems to stay off (but I no longer trust it to stay there).

With that privacy setting *off,* the dash no longer shows me the results, but **the filters are still available** and I want them completely gone. (I don't ever need *weather* in my dash and I don't even *know* what "Skimlinks" is.)

--> How do I get rid of this?! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what about dpkg -l | grep lens

Comment: also it is in the privacy statement if you read it that you must do the following: Go to system settings > Click the Security & Privacy icon > click the Search tab, and toggle the **Include online search results** option to **Off**

Comment: Also, restart lightdm or log out and then log back in.

Comment: Okay **now** I'm confused... I had just restarted and confirmed that the problem still persisted; yes, it did: I still had all those filters shown in the screenshot above. And that privacy setting as "on" again; I turned it off again. Now I've restarted *again* and the privacy setting is "off" *and all those extra filters are gone now.* I don't understand how that worked, but I'm happy to have it resolved (for now, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove some scopes thru a package manager, synaptic works well.

The other way for any unwanted that remain is to open the `Applications` lens. Scroll down to `Dash plugins`, click on the 1st one listed. If wanted click on > to move to next plugin. If not wanted then click on `disable`, then > twice to go to the next scope. Repeat as desired to move thru all the scopes disabling ones you don't want.

A log in/out may be required to reflect changes.